# Не отправляется email

Tags: php

Для отправки простейшего сообщения достаточно же использовать функцию `mail()`?
Но почему-то данная функция при проверке возвращает мне `false`. В чем может быть проблема?

```
mail('gribkovartem@gmail.com', 'Test', 'testtesttest');
```

Comment: Возможно на вашем сервере не настроен sendmail.

Comment: Не покидать ощущение, что отправку вы пытаетесь сделать на локальном сервере, а словить письмо - в инете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример функции:

```
  mail($to, $tema, $text, $header);
```

Где `$to` - кому, `$tema` - тема, `$text` - текст, `$header` - заголовки

Пример заголовков

```
$email_header = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$email_header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
$email_header .= "From: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']." <admin@".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].">\r\n";
```

Попробуйте добавить заголовки, возможно, это поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться "sendmail".

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так. В регу:

```
mail($to, 'Подтверждение регистрации на сайте site.com', "Подтвердите ваш аккаунт, нажав на <a href=\"http://site.com/confirm.php?email={$to}\">эту ссылку</a>");
```

confirm.php:

```
$password = 'password'; // генерируем пароль
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `confirmed` = 1, `password` = '{$password}' WHERE `email` = '{$_GET[email]}'");
mail($_GET['email'], 'Ваши регистрационные данные от site.com', "Ваш пароль: {$password}");
```